# How to check invalid \cite{ENTRY} entries?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

When I reference to non exiting bibliography entry

```
See \cite{NON EXISTING}
```

Instead of error, I result in document with

```
See [?]
```

How to do `\cite{}` checking ? I'd like to prevent citing non-exiting entries.

Comment: You get a warning in the log-file.

Comment: Maybe the [`refcheck`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcheck) package can help. `:)`

Comment: Checking log file solved my problem :) : `grep 'LaTeX Warning' *.log` . What about `refcheck` - it's not present in my system so I haven't checked it.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel - Maybe put your answers on bottom , so I could up-vote or select as solving question

Answer (score 1):

When you compile with a citation of an entry that doesn't exist, you will get a message in your log as:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `NonExistant' on page 2 undefined on input line 51.
```

you log file is situated in the same file as your .tex file with the same name and a .log extension

It would be good practise I suppose to search your log file for the `LaTeX Warning` string.